# PHP ftp_fget simultaneous downloading

Tags: php, ftp

I need to download a bunch of files using FTP.

I am allowed up to 5 connections. I can use FileZilla to download the files pretty quick but I would like this to be done using PHP for various reasons.

Is it possible to simultaneously download files this way instead of going from file to file? Is there a difference, download speed-wise, to create multiple connections? I need them downloaded as quickly as possible.

Comment: I'm pretty new here and first time I tried to accept an answer it wouldnt let me so I never got to it later. But I've always gotten my questions answered here - but thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to download more than one file at a at time

use [ftp_nb_fput()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-fput.php) and then a loop that uses [ftp_nb_continue](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-continue.php) for each handler, alternating.

You will still be limited to the maximum bandwidth available to you, so simultaneous downloads may not be any faster

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do this with curl! http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: are there any benefits to doing this w/ curl? i already set it up with php's ftp function..

Comment: curl is a powerful library, you can configure the handler the way you want and there are so many features available too!